# pg-promise: Casting stored procedure args to the dataType of that column in postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.4, pg-promise

Trying to insert into PostgreSQL via a stored procedure using pg-promise.
I see only integers/timestamp without.t.z  arguments are successfully inserted.
Whenever the stored procedure contains boolean, character varying arguments, the procedure fails with :

> function(integer, undefined, undefined) does not exist.

Even the simplest of stored procedures (totally unambiguous) fails with this error.

Faced the same issue in Java too, but could explicitly cast each argument there like

> " 51212::INTEGER,'Name'::CHARACTER VARYING,   '2016-07-26'::timestamp without time zone"

whereas pg-promise does not allow me to cast arguments.

Is it actually possible to call a Postgres stored procedure without explicit casting, be it from Java or Javascript? If so, how?

What works is: simply use double quotes instead of single....

```
db.proc('storedproc', [124, "AIM", new Date('2016-08-22'),false]).then()
```

Comment: Call you procedure as a simple query `query("select * from functionName($1::cast1, $2::cast2)", [param1, param2])`.

Comment: This is the SP I am trying to execute:                                                     SELECT put_asset_alias(
 51212::INTEGER,
 'Name'::CHARACTER VARYING,
 '2016-07-26'::timestamp without time zone,
 'hm'::CHARACTER VARYING, 
 '2016-07-26'::timestamp without time zone,
 'h'::CHARACTER VARYING,
 0::boolean
);                                 The error always points to '::char,, vary.. ' and says... token expected.       Note: I can execute the exact same call from Java.

Comment: I don't think that `CHARACTER VARYING`can be used for type casting. You can cast it as `::TEXT` ;)

Comment: Casting as text did not work either. But, using double quotes worked.I must hv done something wrong when I tried double quotes earlier. Sometimes reallyy........ !!!!!         Simply,                     db.proc('storedProc', [124, "AIMING", new Date('2016-08-22'), false]).then...  Thanks again!